# How do I draw polygons in Carto Builder?

Tags: polygon, carto

I am trying to add an area around a data point to show its reach. I.e. draw a polygon in reference to a point.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you mean [point style by a certain value](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value)?

Comment: I believe so? I essentially have a domestic water line and it feeds a certain area that I want to depict on Carto. I only have a PDF of the area it is feeding, so I need to draw it in but I do not know how.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, I recommend having a look at [this tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), and check CARTO documentation before asking. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new layer and draw that custom polygon (following your pdf as a reference) using the BUILDER Geometry Edition tool as explained [in this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/data-and-sql/create-and-manage-data-by-drawing-geometries).